# HightChart graph lable cutoff issue

Tags: highcharts

here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/n4k6u72r/10/

The text label is not showing proper

I had try with :

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />`

in my main screen but not working.

Comment: @ewolden in your demo Left side is not working

Comment: Yuuup,, Working :) Thanks @ewolden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set [margins](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.marginRight) for the left and right side to fully display the labels. Like this:

```
chart: {
  marginLeft: 70,
  marginRight: 70,
  ...
}
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/n4k6u72r/13/